# R: provide a string to be used as an equation

Tags: r

I have a large data frame (`df`) I need to have filtered by one numeric variable (`NumericVar`).
I want to use a dynamic filter, that would be defined elsewhere in the program (`FilterCond`).

for example, I want to define

```
FilterCond <- '<100'
```

and later:

```
df[df$NumericVar FilterCond, ]
```

I found some answers mentioning eval(parse()) as a possible solution, I cant get it to work in the filtering scenario.
Can I apply the filter, although it is provided as a string?

Comment: `eval(parse(text=FilterCond))` - also, did you mean to use `df` then `dataframe$...` or should they be the same?

Comment: This is simply not a good way to achieve your aim. You should avoid using the `eval(parse(string))` idiom as much as possible. It poses security concerns, is slower than most alternatives, is harder to debug, and can throw up unexpected warnings on CRAN checks. Why not make `FilterCond` a simple function like `FilterCond <- function(x) x < 100` , allowing `df[FilterCond(df$NumericVar), ]` or `subset(df, FilterCond(NumericVar))`?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen, you are right. it's just the example I wrote for the question. I will correct the post. Thanks.

Comment: @AllanCameron, may aim is not ti use the 'eval(parse(string))' method, but to use a dynamic condition, Your suggestion seems very useful. If you'll write it as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using the `eval(parse(string))` idiom as much as possible. It poses security concerns, is slower than most alternatives, is harder to debug, and can throw up unexpected warnings on CRAN checks.

A more idiomatic way to create predicates is via a simple function:

```r
FilterCond <- function(x) x < 100
```

This allows

```r
subset(df, NumericVar |> FilterCond())
```

If you like, you could even create a predicate factory function:

```r
make_filterCond <- function(predicate) {
  
  f <- alist(x =, {})
  f[[2]] <- as.list(match.call())$predicate
  as.function(f)
}
```

This allows

```r
FilterCond <- make_filterCond(x < 100)

subset(df, NumericVar |> FilterCond())
```

Or, for a more complex and real-world case,

```r
iris_cond <- make_filterCond(is.numeric(x) & !is.na(x) & x > 4)

subset(iris, Sepal.Width |> iris_cond())
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 16          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
#> 33          5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
#> 34          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2  setosa
```